# I am unable to set the cookies received from the response

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

I am running a localhost React App on port 3000 and a Express server on port 4000. When I run the request from Postman, the cookies are being set and for any request made after that the cookie is being attached to the headers. But in React, I am getting response cookie but when I send another request, the cookie that was received is not being attached to the header. Please help me how to do it.

My server is using this function to attach the cookies to the response:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.generateToken = (res, userId) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: '5d',
  });

  res.cookie('jwt', token, {
    path:'/',
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false, 
    sameSite: 'None', 
    maxAge: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
  });
};
```

And this function is used to authenticate the cookie:

```js
exports.protect = async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  try {
    token = req.cookies.jwt;
  } catch (error) {
    sendError(res, "Invalid Token Provided. Please Login again to continue", 401);
    createError(error, "middleware/authMiddleware.js/protect");
    return; // Stop execution here after sending the error response
  }

  const role = req.body.role || req.params.role;

  if (!token) {
    return sendError(res, "Invalid:token Please Login to Continue", 401);
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    if (!isValidObjectId(decoded.userId)) {
      return sendError(res, "Unautherised Access", 401);
    }
    
    const user = await Users.findOne({_id:decoded.userId});

    if(!user) return sendError(res,"Invalid User Id Found",404);
    
    if (role !== user.role) {
      return sendError(res, "You are not authorized to access this route", 401);
    }

    if (user._id!=decoded.userId) {
      return sendError(res, "User Not Found", 404);
    }

    req.user = {
      _id: decoded.userId,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      role: user.role,
      department: user.department,
    };

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    sendError(res, "Invalid Token Provided. Please Login again to continueee", 401);
    createError(error, "middleware/authMiddleware.js/protect");
  }
};
```

I am running the signup route which is sending the cookie to the browser but it is not being set:

[image: Screenshot of the response cookie]

But in the Application tab the cookie is not visible:

[image: ScreenShot of the application tab in the chrome inspect]

The React code I am using to send the request is:

```js
const handleVerifyUser = async () => {
  setName(() => "");
  setPassword(() => "");
  setDepartment(() => "");
  setEmail(() => "");
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/v2/verifyUser", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    credentials: "same-origin",
    withCredentials: true,

    body: JSON.stringify({
      token: otp,
    }),
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
  if (data.success === true) {
    setMessage(() => data.message);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMessage(null);
    }, 2000);
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    setMessage(() => data.message);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMessage(null);
    }, 2000);
  }
};
```

I am getting the response

> { message: "Invalid:token Please Login to Continue" }

After sending the request if I see the network tab the cookie that was received was not sent as a header of the next request

[image: Screenshot of the network tab after sending the request]

I tried multiple times from different browsers but the cookie was not being set anywhere

Answer (score 0):

`SameSite=None` has specific requirements on security. Specifically, your server URL must be served over `https://` and the cookie must be marked as `Secure`.

For development environments where both client and server operate on the same hostname (ie `localhost`), you can use "Lax" which is also the default value.

```js
res.cookie('jwt', token, {
  path: '/',
  httpOnly: true, //  client side JS should not have access
  secure: false,
  sameSite: 'Lax',
  maxAge: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
```

For production mode, you'll need an HTTPS enabled server and `SameSite=None; Secure`

```js
res.cookie('jwt', token, {
  path: '/',
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  sameSite: 'None',
  maxAge: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
```

You can combine these with a check on `process.env.NODE_ENV` to make your code easier to use in either environment.

```js
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

res.cookie('jwt', token, {
  path: '/',
  httpOnly: true, //  client side JS should not have access
  secure: isProd,
  sameSite: isProd ? 'None' : 'Lax',
  maxAge: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
```

You'll also want to configure your [CORS middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) to allow *credential* requests

```js
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://client'], // cannot be '*'
  credentials: true,
}));
```

---

FYI the [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) object passed to `fetch()` does **not** support a `withCredentials` property. Don't confuse it with `XMLHttpRequest`.

The property you want for cross-origin `fetch()` requests with cookies is

```js
fetch(url, {
  method,
  credentials: 'include', // 
  // ...
});
```

For `XMLHttpRequest` it is

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, url);
xhr.withCredentials = true; // 
// ...
```

And for Axios it is

```js
axios({
  url,
  method,
  withCredentials: true, // 
  // ...
});

// or

axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
axios.post(url, data, { withCredentials: true });
// etc...
```

It's **very important** that you use the relevant *credentials* options in **ALL** requests. One common pattern I see on Stack Overflow is forgetting to include it on the initial *login* request.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was having the problem because i used `secure:false,sameSite:'None'` and the browser was not able to read it ,I changed it to `secure:true,sameSite:'None'` and i added the code ```app.use(cors({
    origin: true, 
    credentials: true,
  }));``` in the index.js file where the app was listening. Now I am getting the correct response and the cookies are being sent and stored