# Why is my express session variable undefined?

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, express-session

We have an Express application with authentication routes (postLogin and getLogin) and session configuration set up using express-session. Despite configuring sessions, I encounter an issue where session data is not persisting between requests.

PostLogin: I am creating the session for the user here.

```
const postLogin = async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    try {
        // Query database for user
        const user = await getUserByUsername(username);
        // Validate password
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!passwordMatch) {
            res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid username or password' });
            return;
        }
        // Set session data
        req.session.user = {
            id: user.id,
            username: user.username
        };
        req.session.save();
        res.json({
            loggedIn: true, 
            username: user.username
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Login error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
};
```

GetLogin: Checking for user session data on page refresh in my front end to see if user session is available. This always returns null for some reason.

```
const getLogin = (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user && req.session.user.username) {
        res.json({
            loggedIn: true,
            username: req.session.user.username
        });
    } else {
        res.json({ loggedIn: false });
    }
};
```

Express Session Config: (Update): edited cors to allow origin requests.

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();



app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:5173'], // cannot be '*'
  credentials: true,
}));

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'production',
        sameSite: process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'production' ? 'none' : 'lax'
    }
}));
```

Front-end axios request (React JSX)

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const AccountContext = createContext();

const UserContext = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ loggedIn: null });
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Using effect");
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login", {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "include", // Include credentials in the request
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response || !response.ok) {
          setUser({ loggedIn: false });
          return null;
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data) {
          setUser(data);
          navigate("/home");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
        setUser({ loggedIn: false });
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AccountContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </AccountContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default UserContext;
```

Comment: The presence of `sameSite` hints that you're using cross-origin requests. You'll need to configure the `cors()` middleware with a known `origin` and `credentials: true`. You'll also need to make the requests with the appropriate `credentials: 'include'` for `fetch()` or `withCredentials` for `XMLHttpRequest`. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77560313/283366) help?

Comment: Hi Phil thanks for your response. Is fetch required or can I use Axios? (React JSX).

Comment: Axios is fine. You can see at the bottom of the linked answer there's a reference

Comment: Ok let me try this I'll get back to you, thank you again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257157/discussion-between-dion-and-phil).

Comment: Did you also include `credentials: 'include'` in the login POST request?

Comment: Thank you Phil, the problem has been solved with your help. I forgot to include credentials in the POST login and POST register. I've been on this problem for days and you solved it in minutes. Engineers like you make the lives of people easy. Thanks so much, and.. keep doing what you're doing. The good karma will return :).

Comment: If the other answer I linked helped, feel free to give it an upvote. I can't use that post as a duplicate target until it's accepted or upvoted and I don't think the original asker is coming back any time soon 